# Is there a way to trace overlapping instance decision

Tags: haskell, ghc

Is it possible to know (at compile time) which instance does the compiler chose in case of overlapping instance ?

Contrived example,

```
{-# LANGUAGE IncoherentInstances #-}


class Transformable a b where
  transform :: a -> b

instance Transformable a Int where
  transform _ = 17

instance a ~ b => Transformable a b where
  transform x = x
```

What is the result of `tranform (1:: Int) :: Int` ? (1 or 17)
Is there a way to know when instanciating `Transformable Int Int` if the compiler schose instance 1 or instance 2 ?
It is also sometime usefull when there is no overlap but the chain of instanciation is complicated.

Comment: Look at the GHC Core. Use `-ddump-simpl` and search for the dictionary arguments.

Comment: I'm curious. What's the differences between `a ~ b => Transformable a b` and `Transformable a a` ?

Comment: I'm not sure I need it in that case. I simplified my code which neede it. There a great explanation [there](http://chrisdone.com/posts/haskell-constraint-trick)

Comment: @chi `-ddump-simpl` gives something indeed but it's quite opaque. Could you give me a hint on what to look for ?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `Debug.Trace`:

```
import Debug.Trace
...

instance Transformable a Int where
  transform _ = trace "using Int definition" 17

instance a ~ b => Transformable a b where
  transform x = trace "using a ~ b definition" x
```

Comment: The OP asks: "Is it possible to know __(at compile time)__..."

Comment: I did that and its a indeed. But I'm interested to know if there is magic flag to see at compile time . +1anyway